# Questions about Qubic

Tags: discussion, site-scope

There are a few recent questions related to Qubic, for example:

[What are the differences between Qubic smart contracts and Ethereum smart contracts?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/what-are-the-differences-between-qubic-smart-contracts-and-ethereum-smart-contra)

[What smart contract language does IOTA use?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/what-smart-contract-language-does-iota-use)

I'm very curious about the technical aspects of Qubic and have some questions on my own. At the same time, if I'm not mistaken, there is very little official information available about the technical details of Qubic. This may create lots of unsubstantiated speculation in the answers.

Is it ok to ask questions about Qubic now, or should I wait until more information is released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest (especially for questions about Abra or Smart Contracts) to wait until either a language spec or a whitepaper has been released (or maybe a working prototype). Otherwise we can all only speculate, and if we try to answer we can expect a large amount of downvotes on the answers when more information is released... (I'm seeing it right now in my reputation changes...)